# usage of static linked library (MSVS2008) in MSVS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries

Will i be able to use a static linked library compiled under MS Visual Studio 2008 in MS Visual Studio 2010 projects without to rebuild/recompile it?

I'm talking about the OpenSSL library, which is only available for VS2008 in a precompiled binary package.

Comment: yes i do. sorry, forget to bring this up.

Comment: You can just get the source instead of the binaries and compile it with VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenSSL itself is only C, your resulting executable will require both VS 2008 (MSVCR90) and VS 2010 run time libraries, but it should work and be usable. I'd suggest recompiling the OpenSSL with VS 2010 as well.